# Why we use wavelength to divide light into rays, wave and particles?

Tags: optics, visible-light, wave-particle-duality, wavelength

I want to ask something about light, light can be defined as ray, wave, or particle. The group formed because of the wavelength, if the wavelength is less than the dimension of equipment it is grouped into ray, if the wavelength is equal to the dimension of equipment it is grouped into wave, and the last if the wavelength is bigger than the dimension of the equipment it is grouped into particles/foton. My question is, why we use wavelength to divided into ray, wave and particles?

Comment: I had not heard this specific classification based only on wavelength, although it makes some sense: the behavior of light in some situation depends on how relevant is its wave-nature. This is general for waves, although the comparison is not completely correct. I mean you can find similar behavior in other wave-phenomena, except for the particle-like behavior, which seems to be only a quantum phenomenon.

Answer (score 2):

If the wavelength is really small, one can neglect diffraction effects and light can be viewd as rays. Once the wavelenght becomes comparable to the the size of the object with which it is interacting (e.g. a hole in an opaque screen), diffraction effect becomes important and one needs the wave picture of light to explain diffraction phenomena.
But I don't agree when you say

> if the wavelength is bigger than the dimension of the equipment it is grouped into particles/foton

Particle like behavior becomes important at high energy (which correspond to very short wavelength,e.g. UV, X-ray or gamma ray) because then the light interact with the atoms and the molecules in a way that is only describable with the quantum picture of light, the photons. It is also important if the light intensity is extremely low so the photon flux is small enough to have to take into account single photon behavior. A good example is the double slit experiment done with a single photon source where diffraction effect and particle behavior both appear: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles